# How to carry out this aggregation in python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, aggregation

I have the following list of dictionaries which contains the `country` and the values for corresponding servers.

```
[
    {'country': 'KR', 'values': ['Server1']},
    {'country': 'IE', 'values': ['Server1', 'Server3', 'Server2']},
    {'country': 'IE', 'values': ['Server1', 'Server3']},
    {'country': 'DE', 'values': ['Server1']},
    {'country': 'DE', 'values': ['Server2']},
]
```

Now I need to calculate the percentage of each server for a particular country. So for instance, for `IE` the sum total of both the lists is `5` . Hence the percentage will be calculated as `(2/5)*100` for `Server1` as there are two `Server1` out of five for `IE` and similarly for the rest and then add the percentage for `Server1` in the dict with `percent` as key. So essentially for the above structure the output becomes.

```
[
    {"country": "KR", "percent": "100.0000", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]},
    {"country": "IE", "percent": "40.000", "values": ["Server1-40.0", "Server3-40.0", "Server2-20.0"]},
    {"country" : "DE", "percent" : "50.0", "values" : ["Server1-50.0", "Server2-50.0"]},
]
```

I tried the following code.

```
for i in range(len(response) - 1):
   for j in range((i+1), len(response) - 1):
     if response[i]['country'] == response[j]['country']:
       print response[i]['country'], response[j]['country']
       total = len(response[i]['values']) +  len(response[j]['values'])
       print total
       for item in response[i]['values']:
         for ktem in response[j]['values']:
           if item == ktem:
              if item == 'Server1':
                response[i]['percent'] =  200/total
              else:
                response[i][percent] = 0
              del response[j]
```

I am stuck to proceed further to get the percentage part correct. Any help?

Comment: the value of percent is not unique per country: for example, for "IE", percent should be 40 for server1 and 3 but 20 for server2 ...

Comment: Yes , the percent field gets populated with the percent value for `Server1` only.

Comment: Please directly tell us what you want result.

Comment: I have specified the output in the question.

Comment: Although it needs to take some time, I have a good solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a more compact method.

I think it's more readable and easy to understand. You can refer as below:

This is your var I delcare `response`:

```
response = [
    {'country': 'KR', 'values': ['Server1']},
    {'country': 'IE', 'values': ['Server1', 'Server3', 'Server2']},
    {'country': 'IE', 'values': ['Server1', 'Server3']},
    {'country': 'DE', 'values': ['Server1']},
    {'country': 'DE', 'values': ['Server2']},
]
```

Let's merge the values.

```
new_res = {}
for e in response:
    if e['country'] not in new_res:
        new_res[e['country']] = e['values']
    else:
        new_res[e['country']].extend(e['values'])
```

You can print `new_res` if you want to know its content. It's like as below:

```
{
    'KR': ['Server1'],
    'DE': ['Server1', 'Server2'],
    'IE': ['Server1', 'Server3', 'Server2', 'Server1', 'Server3']
}
```

Invoking `collections` module collects elements:

```
from collections import Counter
new_list = []
for country, values in new_res.items():
    # elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values
    merge_values = Counter(values)

    # calculate percentage
    new_values = []
    total = sum(merge_values.values())    
    for server_name, num in merge_values.items():
        #ex: Server1-40.0
        new_values.append("{0}-{1:.1f}".format(server_name, num*100/total))

    percent = merge_values["Server1"]*1.0*100/total

    new_list.append({"country": country,
                     "percent": percent,
                     "values": new_values})
```

You can print `new_list` when finishing calculating result:

```
[{'country': 'KR', 'percent': 100.0, 'values': ['Server1-100.0']},
 {'country': 'DE', 'percent': 50.0,  'values': ['Server1-50.0', 'Server2-50.0']},
 {'country': 'IE', 'percent': 40.0,  'values': ['Server1-40.0', 'Server2-20.0', 'Server3-40.0']}]
```

So you can get answer you want.

Comment: Don't forget the percentage field (though the output of question is a little silly)

Comment: That Counter class is pretty handy.  Instead of the lists in the `new_res` you could just use the `Counter` instead

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have

```
orig = [
    {'country': 'KR', 'values': ['Server1']},
    {'country': 'IE', 'values': ['Server1', 'Server3', 'Server2']},
    {'country': 'IE', 'values': ['Server1', 'Server3']},
    {'country': 'DE', 'values': ['Server1']},
    {'country': 'DE', 'values': ['Server2']},
]
```

You can create a new dictionary that has a list of what servers are in what countries and their counts

```
newDict = {}
for c in orig:
    if c['country'] not in newDict:
        newDict[c['country']] = dict()
    for s in c['values']:
        if s in newDict[c['country']]:
            newDict[c['country']][s] = newDict[c['country']][s] + 1
        else:
            newDict[c['country']][s] = 1
```

which will be of the form:

```
{'KR': {'Server1': 1}, 
 'DE': {'Server1': 1, 'Server2': 1}, 
 'IE': {'Server1': 2, 'Server2': 1, 'Server3': 2}}
```

You can then calculate the percentages as such:

```
output = []
for country in newList:
    total = 0
    for server in newList[country]:
        total = total + newList[country][server]    
    output.append({"country": country, "percent": (100.0 * newList[country]['Server1'])/total})
```

which will produce

```
[{'country': 'KR', 'percent': 100.0}, 
 {'country': 'DE', 'percent': 50.0}, 
 {'country': 'IE', 'percent': 40.0}]
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to optimize and add the other fields that you want